# Writing tuple to specific column index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to insert a tuple to a newly created field at a specific index value, and I am seeing a 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.' error.

I think that means this is unacceptable approach, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

```
import numpy as np


#create new column
results_df['R_INDEX'] = np.nan

#extract index from fuzzy match process.extractBests and insert into  i's array location
for i in title_candidate:
    lookup = process.extractBests(i,reference,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,score_cutoff=100)
    if lookup:
        title, score, t_index = zip(*lookup)       #split into separate tuples
        f = title_candidate.index(i)               #use index() to find location of ith entry
        results_df['R_INDEX'].iloc[f] = t_index    #insert tuple into dataframe column for ith entry
```

Comment: I discovered np.nan sets an array value, looking for a single number value. This means it won't accept tuples. So I changed ```=.np.nan``` to ```=""``` and it works!

Comment: Errors aside, why not construct the column properly instead of making an empty one and assigning each value individually?

Comment: What's the best way to construct a new column in my DataFrame? I'm still learning best practices.

Comment: _What's the best way to construct a new column in my DataFrame?_ I'm not entirely certain how it would be done here, since we're missing part of the program, but usually you would assign a structure to the column directly, like `results_df['R_INDEX'] = some_object`.